# matlab2tikz produces heavy to typeset tikz code

Tags: matlab, latex, octave

[`matlab2tikz`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz) is a great package for converting `matlab`/`octave` figures to tikz code.

However if the figure contains a lot of points the resulted tikz code is very heavy for latex to typeset. Some times compilation even fails with the message that: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry`.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`matlab2tikz` has a very clever option of **downsampling** the figures during the conversion to tikz-pgf. It is called `minimumPointsDistance`. This does remedy the situation in most of the times.

However, sometimes it can distort certain "stiff" areas of the curve when the actual number of points kept drops very low. This is illustrated in the following picture

[image]

The blue curve (1184 points) is the original while the red one (117 points) is the reduced. The distortion is obvious.

To deal with this and at the same time keep the number of points low I wrote a new point reduction algorithm which is much more effective (but can be slower sometimes). The results (red curve is 116 points)

[image]

It is clear that the distortion is gone.

But there still is

**one more disadvantage**

that exists in both algorithms. When one converts a batch of figures to tikz, they usually want uniform quality for all reduced diagrams. But sometimes this is not possible (at least without extra effort) because **typically `minimumPointsDistance` must be set differently for each one of the figures** and the results actually depend on the size of the intervals [min_y, max_y] and [min_x, max_x] as well as the number of points in the figure.

So in order to overcome this problem and make `minimumPointsDistance` able to be set at a specific value uniformly for all figures, producing reduced versions of uniform quality, normalisation is used, and now `minimumPointsDistance` "internally" refers to the actual size of the printed-on-paper figure.

You can download the modified matlab2tikz.m file from [here](http://users.auth.gr/konstheo/matlab2tikz_modified.rar) along with instructions.

**NOTE** that exhaustive tests were NOT made so be careful!

Answer (score 2):

(A bit long for a comment)

You can use [matlabfrag](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21286), which converts you're figure to an eps and on compiling the LaTeX, substitutes string data to latex strings. This way you don't have the problem of too great a number of samples. Subsampling is imo bad (unless you have 100k points of course), because you want to keep high resolution vector figures.

Example: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?atstyyu4bj198wp

Comment: +1 upvote, this is a tactic I've used and it has worked nice. I much prefer the feel of tikz graphics though.